# How to count pair objects using treemap in java

Tags: java, treemap

I was trying to have a simple String Pair objects to be counted using a TreeMap.

What I've tried is using this comparator in a treemap, but it still gives me the wrong output as if it compares the pair object to itself:

```
static class Comp implements Comparator<Pair>
{   
    public int compare(Pair s1, Pair s2)
    {   
        boolean c1 = s1.word1.equals(s2.word1),
               c2 = s1.word2.equals(s2.word2),
               c3 = s1.word1.equals(s2.word2),
               c4 = s1.word2.equals(s2.word1);

        if(c1 && c2 || c3 && c4)
            return 0;   
        else if((!c1 && !c2) || (!c3 && !c4))
            return s1.word1.compareTo(s2.word1);
        if(!c1)
            return s1.word1.compareTo(s2.word1);
        else if(!c2)
            return s1.word2.compareTo(s2.word2);
        else if(!c3)
            return s1.word1.compareTo(s2.word2);
        else if(!c4)
            return s1.word2.compareTo(s2.word1);    
        else
            return s1.word1.compareTo(s2.word1);
    }
}
```

Example input would be:

```
<"red", "blue"> , <"blue", "red">, <"red", "red">, <"gray","purple">, <"purple","gray">
```

should output:

```
<"gray", "purple", 2>, <"red", "blue", 2> <"red", "red", 1>
```

instead i get:

```
<"gray", "purple", 1><"red", "blue", 2> <"red", "red", 1><"purple", "gray", 1>
```

Comment: Please re-read the Javadoc for `Comparator`and ensure that you are implementing the ***required*** contract for ordering.

Comment: It may be less complicated to convert each pair to a String in alphabetical order _(ie `["a", "b"]` and `["b", "a"]` both convert to `"a,b"`)_, then just use `String.compareTo(String)` on those outputs

Comment: Pair is just 2 strings, word1 and word2.

Comment: Thats a good idea. I'll come back after I try it

Comment: Did you implement the `.equals()` method on the `Pair` object? "The ordering imposed by a comparator c on a set of elements S is said to be consistent with equals if and only if c.compare(e1, e2)==0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 in S."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are coding your counting, but the sorting works as expected with what you've shown of your code. The only difference I've seen between the code below and your code is that the `Comp` class is not static in mine.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class ComparatorTest {

    public ComparatorTest() {
        Map<Pair, String> x = new TreeMap<>(new Comp());
        x.put(new Pair("red", "blue"), "one");
        x.put(new Pair("blue", "red"), "two");
        x.put(new Pair("red", "red"), "three");
        x.put(new Pair("gray", "purple"), "four");
        x.put(new Pair("purple", "gray"), "five");

        System.out.println(String.format("Print out Map - %s", x.toString()));

        for (Pair pair : x.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Key value <%s, %s, %s>", pair.word1, pair.word2, x.get(pair)));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ComparatorTest();
    }
}

class Pair {
    String word1 = null;
    String word2 = null;

    public Pair(String word1, String word2) {
        this.word1 = word1;
        this.word2 = word2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Pair)) { return false; }

        Pair that = (Pair)obj;

        return ((this.word1.equals(that.word1) && this.word2.equals(that.word2)) || (this.word1.equals(that.word2) && this.word2.equals(that.word1)));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("<%s, %s>", word1, word2);
    }
}

class Comp implements Comparator<Pair> {   
    public int compare(Pair s1, Pair s2) {   
        boolean c1 = s1.word1.equals(s2.word1),
               c2 = s1.word2.equals(s2.word2),
               c3 = s1.word1.equals(s2.word2),
               c4 = s1.word2.equals(s2.word1);

        if(c1 && c2 || c3 && c4)
            return 0;   
        else if((!c1 && !c2) || (!c3 && !c4))
            return s1.word1.compareTo(s2.word1);
        if(!c1)
            return s1.word1.compareTo(s2.word1);
        else if(!c2)
            return s1.word2.compareTo(s2.word2);
        else if(!c3)
            return s1.word1.compareTo(s2.word2);
        else if(!c4)
            return s1.word2.compareTo(s2.word1);    
        else
            return s1.word1.compareTo(s2.word1);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Print out Map - {<gray, purple>=five, <red, blue>=two, <red, red>=three}
Key value <gray, purple, five>
Key value <red, blue, two>
Key value <red, red, three>
```

Comment: Yes I have implemented the .equals() but that didn't work. Also, what I meant by count was frequency of how many times the pair appears. So it would be integer. Sorry if I hadn't made it clear.

Comment: When I put your data in the TreeMap, it considered <"red", "blue"> to be equal to <"blue", "red"> and did a replace because a Map doesn't allow duplicate keys. So I don't know how you are counting how many times the pair occurs, because the pair will only occur once.